# Need to make excel vba vlookup more efficient

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm redesigning some finance reports for my organization to move away from a 3rd party software and looking to use VBA to assist in the automation.  Haven't written VBA since college, so a little rusty.

I've gotten the code to work, however it's very inefficient and is running at about 1000k records every 30 seconds, which is not feasible with a few hundred thousand records.  I've tried several different options that you all have posted in different threads, but must be missing something.

Can you please take a look?

Most threads I've looked at have referenced either a direct input via single cell or same sheet to perform the lookup.  This is a single column on Sheet A (ATB-Allowance Reserving-Calc) and then find lookups in table on Sheet B (Plan Global Lookups).

I do want it to skip over errors, and return nothing.

I've tried the fill down method and copy and paste, neither of which I can get to work with a formula.  They just seem to want to fill with the value from the original formula.

I'm thinking it's not working due to jumping back and forth between sheets, which I've encountered issues with in different calculations.

I'm not one to just try one or two times, so this is definitely me at the end of my rope.

```
Dim GlobalExpPct As Variant

Range("AI2").Select  'Gets historical rates from Plan Global Lookups tab
Do
On Error Resume Next
GlobalExpPct = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -24), Sheets("Plan Global Lookups").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
ActiveCell.value = GlobalExpPct
GlobalExpPct = vbNullString
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop While ActiveCell.Row < 1000 'have this in place to keep it from looping through all the records
```

I suspect the slow processing is due to selecting of the next cell each time, and then essentially calling the worksheet values and formula again.  I'm typically seeing that the formula is returning either null value or getting the same value from the previous formula in the fill down.

Thanks for the help in advance.  This is a great resource as I've been able to solve 99% of my issues so far on this site.

***Edit***

This code provided by Ahmed are working great, but I need one more criteria:

If an additional column ("T" Account Base Class) is "IP", then we can pull from the "Plan Global Lookups A:B" as currently setup.  However, if it's populated otherwise, we'll need to pull from a lookup on another column.  We can duplicate the table on the same sheet or still use column A as the lookup for the plan, whichever is the most efficient.  Here is the code as it stands today which is working perfectly:

```
Sub GetGlobals()

Dim IntervalProcessing60k As Integer
Dim SRow As Long
Dim ERow As Long
Dim Src As Variant
Dim AcctPlan
Dim GlobalExpPct As Variant
Dim AcctPlanRng As Range
Dim Rslt() As Variant
Dim t As Date
Dim GetGlobalTime As Date
Dim ActWs As Worksheet
Dim ATBAllowResCalc As Worksheet


Set ActWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set PlanGlobalWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Global Lookups")
Set ATBAllowResCalc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ATB-Allowance Reserving-Calc")
Set AcctGlobalRng = PlanGlobalWs.Range("A1:B" & PlanGlobalWs.Cells(PlanGlobalWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

t = Now()
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

IntervalProcessing60k = 0
SRow = 2
ERow = LastRow
Src = ActWs.Range("K" & SRow & ":K" & ERow).value
X = 1
For Rw = SRow To ERow
AcctPlan = Src(Rw - SRow + 1, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
GlobalExpPct = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AcctPlan, AcctGlobalRng, 2, False)
On Error GoTo 0
ReDim Preserve Rslt(1 To X)
Rslt(X) = IIf(IsNull(GlobalExpPct), "", GlobalExpPct)
GlobalExpPct = vbNullString
If Rw > 120000 Then Debug.Print Rw, X, Src(Rw - SRow + 1, 1), Rslt(X)
        If X = 60000 Then
        ActWs.Range("AI" & IntervalProcessing60k * 60000 + SRow).Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 1).value = Application.Transpose(Rslt)
        IntervalProcessing60k = IntervalProcessing60k + 1
        X = 1
        ReDim Rslt(1 To 1)
        Else
        X = X + 1
        End If
    Next Rw

ActWs.Range("AI" & IntervalProcessing60k * 60000 + SRow).Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 1).value = Application.Transpose(Rslt)

GetGlobalTime = Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty myself but I will try (1) Use explicit cell references, like cell(i, j) instead of Activecell. (2) Set one cell, the copy it and paste it to a range encompassing all the cells which need to contain the formula.

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Best wishes on your endeavors! Cheers!

Comment: There are a couple things you do to help with this.  I think you'll get the best results from using Excel's Power Query.  Load your data into a table, add it to Power Query and then merge the two tables together.

Comment: Lookup how to find the last row of a range. then look up `For` `Next` looping... Also you vlookup & select are no doubt the issue here in time... you could try `Find` instead and learn how to remove `.select`

Comment: @Jay Nelson, thanks for contacting., i waited for feedback and or acceptance of the answer (at least to keep SO spirit) and meanwhile reduced the time further to 8-9 odd seconds for 120 K. Now regarding the objective in latest edit, I am confusing whether if the lookup value in col B is blank then we require to pull the value from Col T (or IP ) or simply the value is to be picked up from Col T (or IP). Please clarify. it will be a pleasure  to find the solution (it may be easy, if it is as I am understanding) . waiting for feedback. Happy computing.

Comment: Sorry, the post might have been confusing.  I meant that if "T" on the active sheet was "IP", pull from "B" on Plan Global Lookups tab.  If "T" on the active sheet is anything but "IP", then pull from another column on the Plan Global Lookups tab.  If the first lookup is blank, do not default to the second column.  Hope this helps.

Comment: New answer posted. Kindly use "@" with username to notify username about comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try this and see if performance improves

```
Sub testModified()
Dim GlobalExpPct As Variant, Rng As Range, Rw As Long
Dim ValtoLook, Ws As Worksheet, ActWs As Worksheet, tm As Double
tm = Timer
Set ActWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Global Lookups")
'Set Rng = Ws.Range("A:B")
'this would be more efficent
Set Rng = Ws.Range("A1:B" & Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Rw = 2 To 1000
    ValtoLook = ActWs.Range("AI" & Rw).Offset(0, -24).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    GlobalExpPct = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ValtoLook, Rng, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Range("AI" & Rw).Value = GlobalExpPct
    GlobalExpPct = vbNullString
    Next Rw
Debug.Print " Time in second " & Timer - tm; ""
End Sub
```

if i have not correctly guessed the columns and ranges you are working with, may kindly modify them to your requirement.

It could be made efficient if you confirm there is all the values of Column K and AI are values and they are not inter dependent with some formulas etc. the above code may prove sufficient for 1000 rows. But for heavy files with 10-1000 K rows, the code required to be more efficient. in that case Excel cell operations  are to be minimized by using array. Adding above code modified with Array

```
Sub testModifiedArray()
Dim GlobalExpPct As Variant, Rng As Range, Rw As Long
Dim ValtoLook, Ws As Worksheet, ActWs As Worksheet
Dim Rslt() As Variant, Src As Variant, tm As Double
tm = Timer
Set ActWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Global Lookups")
'Set Rng = Ws.Range("A:B")
'next line would be more efficent, You may define range directly if you know the end row
Set Rng = Ws.Range("A1:B" & Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
Src = ActWs.Range("K2:K1000").Value
    For Rw = 2 To 1000
    ValtoLook = Src(Rw - 1, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    GlobalExpPct = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ValtoLook, Rng, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReDim Preserve Rslt(1 To Rw - 1)
    Rslt(Rw - 1) = IIf(IsNull(GlobalExpPct), "", GlobalExpPct)
    'Debug.Print Rslt(Rw - 1)
    GlobalExpPct = vbNullString
    Next Rw
ActWs.Range("AI2").Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Rslt)

Debug.Print " Time in second " & Timer - tm; ""
End Sub
```

Both the code tested with my Guess of Column and ranges. As I personally don't prefer to keep calculations, event processing and screen updating off (in normal cases) i haven't added that standard lines. However you may use these standard techniques, depending on the working file condition.

Edit: modified to accommodate overcome 65K limit of array transpose   limt

```
Option Explicit
Sub testModifiedArray2()
Dim GlobalExpPct As Variant, rng As Range, Rw As Long
Dim ValtoLook, Ws As Worksheet, ActWs As Worksheet
Dim Rslt() As Variant, Src As Variant, tm As Double
Dim Chunk60K As Integer, X As Long, SRow As Long, ERow As Long
tm = Timer
Set ActWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Global Lookups")
'Set Rng = Ws.Range("A:B")
'next line would be more efficent, You may define range directly if you know the end row
Set rng = Ws.Range("A1:B" & Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

Chunk60K = 0
SRow = 2
ERow = 120030
Src = ActWs.Range("K" & SRow & ":K" & ERow).Value
X = 1
    For Rw = SRow To ERow
    ValtoLook = Src(Rw - SRow + 1, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    GlobalExpPct = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ValtoLook, rng, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReDim Preserve Rslt(1 To X)
    Rslt(X) = IIf(IsNull(GlobalExpPct), "", GlobalExpPct)
    GlobalExpPct = vbNullString
    If Rw > 120000 Then Debug.Print Rw, X, Src(Rw - SRow + 1, 1), Rslt(X)
        If X = 60000 Then
        ActWs.Range("AI" & Chunk60K * 60000 + SRow).Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Rslt)
        Chunk60K = Chunk60K + 1
        X = 1
        ReDim Rslt(1 To 1)
        Else
        X = X + 1
        End If
    Next Rw


ActWs.Range("AI" & Chunk60K * 60000 + SRow).Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Rslt)

Debug.Print " Time in second " & Timer - tm; ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahmed AU: the second suggestion worked perfect until about line 9k or so, when it starts to return N/A.  Does this mean the calculation results are not retained after this point?  Thanks!

Comment: it is difficult tell how that's happening since i tested both the code up to 1000 only. Some times with heavy files code works weirdly. Will come back after test with larger makeshift data.

Comment: Thanks.  I incrementally upped the range until it quit, which was around 65,000.  If there's a way to make it run in 50k increments, that would work also.

Comment: Already modified code for working with 60K chunk but delayed to submit due to one silly mistake of mine (while verifying result for RW > 120 K i find it is mismatching. Later found Data in column K > 120000 is in formula `RandomBetween` instead of value and it  is constantly changing). However the latest code is tested number of time and  taking around 70 second only for 120 K rows.No error results are found correct. Pl try latest edited code and feedback.

Comment: This appears to be working, but still testing.  Can you help me understand what's happening if the Rw > 120000?

Comment: Ahmed, made one more comment in the question above if you can take a look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Last Answer modified for improved efficiency and new requirement, Test time to process around 120 K rows is around 6 seconds only. additionally column "T" is tested for a value "IP" and lookup value pulled  up from column B or C accordingly.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetGlobals()
Dim SRow As Long
Dim ERow As Long
Dim Src As Variant, Src2 As Variant
Dim AcctPlan
Dim GlobalExpPct As Variant
Dim AcctPlanRng As Range
Dim Rslt() As Variant
Dim tm As Double
Dim ActWs As Worksheet, PlanGlobalWs As Worksheet
Dim AcctGlobalRng As Range
Dim ATBAllowResCalc As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, X As Long, Rw As Long
Dim LookArr As Variant, LookUpCol As Integer

Set ActWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set PlanGlobalWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Global Lookups")
'Set ATBAllowResCalc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ATB-Allowance Reserving-Calc")
Set AcctGlobalRng = PlanGlobalWs.Range("A1:C" & PlanGlobalWs.Cells(PlanGlobalWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
LookArr = AcctGlobalRng.Value

tm = Timer
LastRow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

SRow = 2
ERow = LastRow
Src = ActWs.Range("K" & SRow & ":K" & ERow).Value
Src2 = ActWs.Range("T" & SRow & ":T" & ERow).Value
ReDim Rslt(1 To ERow - SRow + 1, 1 To 1)

    For Rw = SRow To ERow
    AcctPlan = Src(Rw - SRow + 1, 1)
    GlobalExpPct = ""
       For X = 1 To UBound(LookArr, 1)
            If AcctPlan = LookArr(X, 1) Then
            LookUpCol = IIf(Src2(Rw - SRow + 1, 1) = "IP", 2, 3)    
            GlobalExpPct = LookArr(X, LookUpCol)
            Exit For
            End If
       Next X
    GlobalExpPct = IIf(IsNull(GlobalExpPct), "", GlobalExpPct)
    Rslt(Rw - SRow + 1, 1) = GlobalExpPct
    Next Rw

ActWs.Range("AI" & SRow).Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 1).Value = Rslt
Debug.Print " Time in second " & Timer - tm; ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahmed, this appears to be working great.  Still validating, but thanks so much!  Can you please confirm what the last part of this is doing, specifically the ", 2 , 3".
LookUpCol = IIf(Src2(Rw - SRow + 1, 1) = "IP", 2, 3)

Comment: it is testing whether `Src2` (i.e.Column "T") value of that particular row  is "IP". and  according to set the column to either B (2) or C (3) from lookup table to from pull up required value. If it solved the problem, may please accept the answer by clicking tick mark beside the answer. This is to adhere to SO standard and also tor future readers ease of reference.